# Saving worksheets in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I recently migrated to the most recent version of SQL Developer and I've run into a problem I can't remember how to solve.  I like to save all my worksheets and SQL Developer used to provide a default filename based on the connection name.  Now, the file save dialog is just blank.  Does anyone know how to configured SQL Developer so it provides the filename again?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm still seeing that behavior in version 18.3 on my Mac.

Connection name is 'HR'

SQL Worksheet

File - Save

Defaults filename to HR.sql

[image]

I don't see any preferences that would affect this behavior. What does it default the filename to, untitled? Are you sure your worksheet has a connection attached? If so, what's your connection name? And what version of SQL Developer, Java, and OS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the version I was running was very old.  I upgraded to the latest and greatest version and that solved the problem.  Thanks for the reply!!